# How to profile Akka Java application mailboxes

Tags: java, profiling, akka, typesafe

How can I profile my Java-based Akka application? I looked at the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785307/how-to-profile-akka-applications).

But I found it to be unsatisfactory. The answer says that Typesafe Activator released something called the 'Typesafe Console', but the link in the answer was a deadlink: [Link](http://typesafe.com/blog/typesafe_console_-_now_free_for_developers)

and the other [Link](http://typesafe.com/platform/runtime/console) just redirects you back to
[This Location](http://typesafe.com/activator)

We're running into performance issues with our Akka-Java-based application and we want to identify whether it's an issue in the way we've modeled our actor hierarchy. For example, how can we profile the application in such a way that we can see how many messages are queued in any actor's mailbox at any given point in time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Typesafe Console is being stopped by Typesafe.

You should have a look at the community project [Kamon](http://kamon.io/), it offers several Akka monitoring metrics.

- Message processing times
- Time waiting in mailbox
- Mailbox sizes
- Message flow tracing
- Dispatchers health

Comment: Will this work with Java? Just from a quick glance, it looks like it's only available for Akka-Scala based projects?

Comment: To be honest I never tried Kamon with Java, but according to the google group some people are doing it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/kamon-user/java/kamon-user/v0AvKmld9X4/PcBnlczhZRQJ

Comment: have anyone tried http://mukis.de/pages/monitoring-akka-with-kamon/
I am also looking for this. but could not get working yet